# $K-$rational solution of the equation - Is $\mathbb{Q} \leq \mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots, p-adic-number-theory

Let $P(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x, y]$. We consider the equation $P(x, y)=0$. If $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $P(a, b)=0$ then $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$, is called a rational solution.

If $K$ a field, $\mathbb{Q} \leq K$, then if $(a, b) \in K \times K$ and $P(a, b)=0$ then $(a, b)$ is called a $K-$rational solution.

When $(a, b)$ is a $K-$rational solution does this mean that $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Q}$ ??

For example, $x^2-2$, is $\sqrt{2}$ a $\mathbb{R}-$solution ??

$$$$

I have also an other question...

Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_p, \forall p \in \mathbb{P}$ ??

$$$$

**EDIT:**

If $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ a rational solution of $P(x, y)=0 (1)$, where $P(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x, y]$, then the equation $(1)$ has a $\mathbb{Q}_p-$rational solution $\forall p \leq \infty$.

The (rational) $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a perfect square of a rational $\Leftrightarrow$ when $x$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}_p, \forall p \leq \infty$.

So, something stands in $\mathbb{Q}$ iff it stands in $\mathbb{Q}_p, \forall p \in \mathbb{P}$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of its p-adic completion $\mathbb{Q}_p$. As for any completion of a field $K$, the field itself is embedded into its completion $\widehat{K}$.
If we define the completion as the space of all Cauchy sequences modulo zero sequences, we have the embedding $K\hookrightarrow \widehat{K}$, given by $a\mapsto (a,a,\ldots)$, where $a$ is mapped to the constant Cauchy sequence. As a consequence, the prime field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, so that the characteristic of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is zero.

For the first question, see [K-rational points on algebraic varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_point). It does not necessarily mean that the coordinates are in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ok... I added also an other question at my initial post... Could you have alook at it??

Comment: The last claim of your edit is not true. For example $f(x,y,z)=3x^3+4y^3+5z^3$ has a non-trivial zero over any $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for $p$ prime, but not over $\mathbb{Q}$. See [Hasse principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle).

Comment: In wikipedia there is the following sentence: "certain types of equations have a rational solution if and only if they have a solution in the real numbers and in the p-adic numbers for each prime p." Doesn't this mean that an equation has a rational solution iff it has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p, \forall p \in \mathbb{P}$ ??

Comment: Yes, but only for certain equations, e.g., the ones given in [Hasse-Minkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem). But as I said, $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: In wikipedia there is the following sentence: "in order to determine whether an equation of a certain type has a solution in rational numbers, it is sufficient to test whether it has solutions over complete fields of real and p-adic numbers, where analytic considerations, such as Newton's method and its p-adic analogue, Hensel's lemma, apply." For what type of equations does this stand??

Comment: For quadratic forms, like $Q(x,y,z)=3x^2+4y^2-61z^2$.

Comment: I understand... Thank you!!!